# Django QuerySet select related objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have searched around but have not found a situation like mine. Assuming the use of Django's User Profile method to extend the default user features, how would a multi-object queryset get mapped a queryset of the related object.

For example (in the models):

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=True, blank=True)
```

And inside the view:

```
class Friends(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset=User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        profile = user.userprofile
        profiles = profile.friends.all()
        return profiles  #We want this to be a queryset of users
```

I have tried the following but this only works if `profiles` is of size one.

```
return User.objects.filter(userprofile=profiles)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 return User.objects.filter(userprofile__in=profiles)
```

Comment: Just curious, if we had N UserProfiles and M Users would this be an O(M*N) operation or does django somehow know to optimize it to an O(N) operation?

Comment: this statement will be translated into a single sql statement that look like this

    `select * from users where id in (select user_id from profiles where .....)`

so complexity doesn't increase and remain close to O(N) or maybe O(N*2) ? I am not expert but certainly not O(M * N)

Comment: On a second thought, complexity might be higher (On DB level). to know exact complexity you need to understand how does db engine perform subquery and how it utilize column indexes. all are outside the scope of my knowledge

Comment: how can i get all the Users that have a Userprofile' object related?

Comment: Try ` return User.objects.filter(userprofile_id__isnull=False)`